# Wrong Activity Launching On Start up Android

Tags: android, xml, android-activity

When i start my app it launches the wrong activity, i am new to coding so if you could keep the answer as simple as possible and tell me where i was going wrong it would be great, thanks in advance

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".Dust2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dust2" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="csgosmokes.csgo.dust2" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.default" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Which activity is starting, and which activity would you like to start when the activity is launched?

Comment: This configuration launches MainActivity.

Comment: I am trying to launch MainActivity, but it is launching Dust2 Activity

Comment: How are you "launching your activity"? Are you clicking on the app icon on the HOME screen? or are you launching it from your development environment (IDE, Ecplipse, Android Studio, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="csgosmokes.csgo.dust2" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.default" />
    </intent-filter>
```

From

```
<activity
    android:name=".Dust2"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_dust2" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="csgosmokes.csgo.dust2" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.default" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```